# Change all elements with id='s value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, getelementbyid, getelementsbyname

I have a an input button that is produced by a php for loop.

here is what it outputs:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
```

how can i change the value of all the input's with the id or name "submit"?

i tried `getElementById` but that only changes of the inputs:

```
<script>
var submit_button = document.getElementById('submit');
submit_button.value = 'Next';
</script>
```

i tried `getElementsByName` but that didnt work at all:

```
<script>
var submit_button = document.getElementsByName('submit');
submit_button.value = 'Next';
</script>
```

How can i change the value of all the `input`'s?

**i want regular javascript. if not possible with regular javascript, jquery is fine too.**

Comment: `id` has to be unique on the page or javascript only see's the last one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IDs must be unique, so change them.

You can use **[document.getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)**. Because this returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) you can use the [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) in order to change the value attribute.

```js
document.getElementsByName('submit').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
   ele.value = 'Next';
})
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit1" value="Submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit2" value="Submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit3" value="Submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit4" value="Submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit5" value="Submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit6" value="Submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit7" value="Submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit8" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jquery like so:

```
$("#submit").val("Next");
```

Comment: This is so nice, short, and simple but i wish it was like that in regular javascript.

Comment: Absolutely agreed! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using you can use class since the id is unique as @RiggsFolly suggested so you can add a class for example `class="btn"` and in your js block you can say :

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
```

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
    
    for(i=0; i<x.length; i++){
     x[i].value = "next";
    }
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
```

Answer (score 1):

in jQuery:

```
$('input[name=submit]').val('Next');
```

or in vanilla JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[name=submit]').forEach(function(node){
    node.value = 'Next'
});
```

or to shorten actual the call a bit, putting the querySelectorAll into a reusable utility-function:

```
function $$(selector, ctx=document){
    return Array.from(ctx.querySelectorAll(selector));
}


$$('input[name=submit]').forEach(function(node){
    node.value = 'Next';
});
```

Why wrapping that into an Array? `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, not an Array, so it provides `forEach`, but it doesn't provide all the other neat little functions an array does, like `filter`, `map`, `slice` etc.

Answer (score 0):

An id is supposed to be unique, and getElementById will return only one element.

Instead, you should use the class attribute on your tags and get the list using getElementsByClassName. This returns a collection and you can use a for loop to iterate over it.

```
for ( element in document.getElementsByClassName("submit") )
  element.value = "Next"
```